# VB specific line of text to bold in a multi-line TextBox

Tags: vb.net, fonts, richtextbox

I'm writing a reminder program in vb.net that reads a text file and displays dated entries from today to 14 days from today. I want entries for today's date to be in bold. If it makes any difference I'm using a TextBox instead of Rich TextBox  This is what I've tried:

```
Public Sub getReadFile()

    ' rtfRead is the name of the TextBox
rtfRead.Text = Nothing
' Today, the first read line date
Dim startDate As Date = Date.Now()                                          
    ' First dated line to read
Dim todayDate As String = (GetDateInMyFormat(startDate))                    
    ' The last read line date
Dim endDate As String = (GetDateInMyFormat(DateAdd("d", 14, startDate)))
    ' The first 4 characters of a line. Are the 4 charcters numbers, i.e. yyyy
Dim lineStart As Object
    ' The date at the beginnig of a an entry
Dim lineDate As String = Nothing
    ' Are the first 4 charcters of a line numeric = True
Dim isNum As Boolean = False
    ' TM_Notes.txt
Dim readFile As String = Nothing    
Dim oldFont As Font = rtfRead.Font
Dim boldFont As Font = New Font(rtfRead.Font, FontStyle.Bold)

Try
    ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
    ' The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
    Using sr As New StreamReader("TM_Notes.txt")
        Dim lineRead As String

        ' Read and display lines from the file until the end of
        ' the file is reached.
        Do
            lineRead = sr.ReadLine()

            lineStart = Mid(lineRead, 1, 4)
            isNum = IsNumeric(lineStart)

            If isNum = True Then
                lineDate = GetDateInMyFormat(Mid(lineRead, 1, 10))
            End If

            If lineDate = todayDate Then
                rtfRead.Font = boldFont
            Else
                rtfRead.Font = oldFont
            End If

            If Not (lineRead Is Nothing) And isNum = False And lineDate <= endDate Then
                readFile = readFile + lineRead & vbCrLf
            ElseIf lineDate >= todayDate And lineDate <= endDate Then
                readFile = readFile + lineRead & vbCrLf
            End If

        Loop Until lineRead Is Nothing
    End Using

    rtfRead.Text = readFile

Catch ex As Exception
    ' Let the user know what went wrong.
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
```

I don't get any errors but today's date isn't in bold.

It today is 02-11  then the Test string line should be bold.

2014-02-11: Test string

2014-02-12: Test string 2

**UPDATE**

I've changed to a Rich TextBox and updated my code sample to to reflect my code changes.  I'm still not getting Bold

Comment: Can you post the complete method where your code resides?  It's hard to figure out what is going wrong from the code snippet.

Comment: @wdosanjos Here you go

Comment: Me.Font is the font of the form not of the TextBox control.  Also, with the TextBox control there is no option to bold a single line (it's all the text or nothing).  You need to use the RichTextBox for that.

Comment: @wdosanjos If I'm not bothering you, would you take a look at my changes.

Comment: I  got a function that does this just by passing in the string and the string/s you want formatted. . .

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR If you wouldn't mind I'd love to see it.

Comment: Welcome, just don't have it in the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the function... You pass the text you want to find and the format (bold or italic - 1 or 2). This works really good; you can also expand this to add color if you choose. I hope you find this useful, happy coding!

```
  'Pass in a 1 or 2; one is bold the other is italic'
Private Function FormatText(ByVal TextToFormat As String, ByVal TextFormat As Integer)
    Dim count As New List(Of Integer)()
    For i As Integer = 0 To rText.Text.Length - 1
        If rText.Text.IndexOf(TextToFormat, i) <> -1 Then
            'If the word is found add the index to the list
            count.Add(rText.Text.IndexOf(TextToFormat, i))
        End If
    Next

    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To count.Count - 1
            rText.[Select](count(i), TextToFormat.Length)
            Select Case TextFormat
                Case 1
                    rText.SelectionFont = New Font(rText.Font.FontFamily, rText.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
                Case 2
                    rText.SelectionFont = New Font(rText.Font.FontFamily, rText.Font.Size, FontStyle.Italic)
            End Select
            count.RemoveAt(i)
        Next
    Catch
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: It missing info on how to use this method from the user's code.  It seems the code needs to save all the lines that need to be highlighted and then iterate through then and call this method, right?

Comment: How to use this method? It's a function all he needs to do is pass in what he want's the function will do it for him. This function ititerates through a richtextbox and looks for the occurences, if found lets add the occurence to a list. Then we will go through that list and select what we need to. I tested this with 5,000 rows last night and it was quick, plus it found ANY occurence of what you pass in.

Comment: Oh almost forgot, his string that he wants formatted: readFile, yeah that's it. Here how you use a function if you can't recall how too: FormatText(readFile,1) - for BOLD OR FormatText(readFile,2) - for Italic.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Sorry for the long delay, Life... wdosanjos Did assume correctly that I'm a beginner. However I prefer to try things myself, so I've been playing with this off and on since the 12th and. all day today. I can't figure out what `rText` equals in my code.  Also, Thank you for the FormatText Function I've pretty much figured out how it works.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Also you were right I do know how to use a function but, having FormatText(readFile, 1) saved me the trouble of remembering. :)

Comment: rText would be your rich textbox name and your welcome!

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Sorry to be a pain. I had figured out FormatText Function I did have `rText` replaced with `rtfRead`. So what is var in `var = FormatText(readFile, 1)` and where should I put it in my code.  This way I won't be pestering you.

Comment: If your using a click event per say you would just call it. For example: FormatText("yourstring",1).

Comment: So how ever your calling yours now just call the new function i have provided.

Comment: Why the unnexcept now?